# Senha ou usuario invalido ao logar no banco oracle (ORA-01017)

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, sqldeveloper

Bom dia pessoal,

Estou precisando configurar um ambiente para um curso.

Para isso instalei o banco Oracle e o SQL Developer. No banco oracle tenho o usuário SYS funcionando perfeitamente.

O problema ocorre quando eu crio um novo usuário do banco e ao tentar logar com este novo usuário eu recebo erro de senha invalida, mesmo tendo certeza do usuário e senha.(ERRO ORA-01017)

Já deletei este e tentei criar outros, já alterei a senha mas nada funciona.

Uma observação é que o banco esta me obrigando a criar usuario com o nome começando por C## não sei se tem alguma co-relação.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Qual sistema operacional você está utilizando?

Comment: Oi Samuel, eu estou utilizando o windows 10, 64bits.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta os seguintes passos

- 1- Abre o CMD
- 2- digita: sqlplus "/as sysdba"
- 3- digita: ALTER USER [SEU_USUARIO] IDENTIFIED BY [SUA_SENHA];

  - EXEMPLO: ALTER USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY 1234;
- 4- digita: COMMIT;
- 5- digita: EXIT

Após realizar esses passos tenta fazer o login com a senha que você digitou acima.